# Как расшарить google authenticator?

Tags: 2fa, госуслуги

С недавнего времени ГосУслуги сделали подлянку и теперь требует обязательную 2FA, а рабочая учетка только одна, на которую завязаны другие сервисы, из-за этого много людей теперь стучатся в 1 телефон и просят код из google authenticator'a.

Собственно вопрос, как его расшарить и сделать так, чтобы каждый пользователь (довереннный) мог его посмотреть?

Отдельный телефон с установленным google authenticator'ом на нем тоже не лучший вариант, т.к. есть люди, которые работают на удаленке, им код нужен тоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один аккаунт может быть установлен на несколько телефонов. (Подсказка: QR-rкод для экспорта/импорта аккаунта можно сфотографировать и распечатать на бумажке или переслать картинку по почте, или разметить на сайте куда имеют доступ только ваши сотрудники...)

Проблему утечки аккаунта, вместе с потерянным телефоном или вследствие недобросовестности сотрудников, решить будет невозможно.

---

Можно написать свой корпоративный сайтик, который будет требовать отдельной аутентификации и будет возвращать только текущий код.
Исходник аутентификатора открыт:
https://github.com/google/google-authenticator
https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-android
https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam

По крайней мере, сможете блокировать аккаунты / менять пароль,.. сотрудников потерявших телефон.

Comment: Спасибо, попробуем вариант с одним QR

Comment: Всё сработало, просто сделал "Экспорт" из google приложения, странно, что сначала не нашел этот функционал, спасибо!